# DevOps Pipeline Can't Restore Using Artifact Feed

Tags: .net, azure-devops, nuget

I'm working on an Azure DevOps pipeline. We recently started publishing module packages to an artifact feed and new projects use `<PackageReference>` to import those modules as NuGet packages.

Now the build step in our pipeline can't load the NuGet packages.

```
Starting: Build
==============================================================================
Task         : .NET Core
Description  : Build, test, package, or publish a dotnet application, or run a custom dotnet command
Version      : 2.221.0
Author       : Microsoft Corporation
Help         : https://docs.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/dotnet-core-cli
==============================================================================
C:\Windows\system32\chcp.com 65001
Active code page: 65001
Info: .NET Core SDK/runtime 2.2 and 3.0 are now End of Life(EOL) and have been removed from all hosted agents. If you're using these SDK/runtimes on hosted agents, kindly upgrade to newer versions which are not EOL, or else use UseDotNet task to install the required version.
C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\dotnet\dotnet.exe build "-dl:CentralLogger,\"D:\a\_tasks\DotNetCoreCLI_5541a522-603c-47ad-91fc-a4b1d163081b\2.221.0\dotnet-build-helpers\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.MSBuild.Logger.dll\"*ForwardingLogger,\"D:\a\_tasks\DotNetCoreCLI_5541a522-603c-47ad-91fc-a4b1d163081b\2.221.0\dotnet-build-helpers\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.MSBuild.Logger.dll\"" --configuration Release
MSBuild version 17.3.2+561848881 for .NET
  Determining projects to restore...
##[error]MyApp\MyModule\MyModule.csproj(0,0): Error NU1301: Unable to load the service index for source https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/MyOrg/MyProj/_packaging/MyFeed/nuget/v3/index.json.
D:\a\1\s\MyApp\MyModule\MyModule.csproj : error NU1301: Unable to load the service index for source https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/MyOrg/MyProj/_packaging/MyFeed/nuget/v3/index.json. [D:\a\1\s\MySolution.sln]
...
```

The run doesn't fail explicitly, it just re-tries to load from the feed over and over until I cancel the pipeline (I let it run for double the usual build time to be sure it wasn't just taking longer than expected).

This is my pipeline up to the failing build step:

```
trigger: 
- "none"

pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-2022'

variables:
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'
  dotNetFramework: 'net6.0'
  dotNetVersion: '6.0.x'

steps:
- task: UseDotNet@2
  inputs: 
    version: $(dotNetVersion)

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'Restore dotnet tools'
  inputs:
    command: custom
    custom: 'tool'
    arguments: 'restore'

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'Generate license info file using dotnet-project-licenses'
  inputs:
    command: custom
    custom: 'tool'
    arguments: 'run dotnet-project-licenses -i "." -u -o --outfile "./licenses.txt" --packages-filter "/My.*/"'
    
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'Build'
  inputs:
    command: 'build'
    arguments: --configuration $(buildConfiguration)
```

And this is the nuget.config file I use:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <packageSources>
    <add key="nuget.org" value="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" protocolVersion="3" />
    <add key="DevExpress" value="https://nuget.devexpress.com/<api-key>/api" />
    <add key="MyFeed" value="https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/MyOrg/MyProj/_packaging/MyFeed/nuget/v3/index.json" />
  </packageSources>
</configuration>
```

I know that the feed URL is correct, because I can restore the solution in my IDE. Unfortunately, I don't get more information about what went wrong from the pipeline run, but I suspect it might be an authorization problem.

The project build service user has Contributor access to the feed as well. The same user also publishes the modules, so this shouldn't be the issue.

I tried [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59818248/3287590) to no success. The PAT I used was my personal token with read access to the artifacts.

Now I'm running out of ideas on how to fix this.

Comment: Try adding the `NuGetAuthenticate` task before running restore

Comment: @zivkan I tried this after writing this post. unfortunately it didn't work either

Comment: @zivkan I solved the issue with Kevin Lu-MSFT's answer, but when I removed the NuGetAuthenticate step, it failed again. looks like both answers are necessary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Error NU1301: Unable to load the service index for source https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/MyOrg/MyProj/_packaging/MyFeed/nuget/v3/index.json.

Based on the error message, you need to check if the Feed and the Pipeline are in the same Project.

If they are in the different projects, you can refer to the following steps to solve the issue:

1.Check the permission of the Build Service account(Project Level and Collection level).

Here are the steps:

Step1: Navigate to **Artifacts ->Target Feed ->Feed Settings -> Permission**.

Step2: Grant the Build service account Contributor Role . Build service account name: `ProjectnamethePipelinelocated Build Service (Organization name)` and `Project Collection Build Service(Orgname)`

For example:

[image]

2.If the feed and the pipeline are in different projects, you need to **disable** the `Limit job authorization scope to current project for non-release pipelines` option is Enabled in **Project Settings -> Settings**.

For example:

[image]

**Note:** To disable this option, you need to disable the option in `Organization Settings-> Settings` first. Then you could disable the option in Project level.

On the other hand, if you want to use the personal PAT to authenticate the feed, you can add the PAT to nuget.config file.

For example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <packageSources>
    <add key="nuget.org" value="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" protocolVersion="3" />
    <add key="Microsoft Visual Studio Offline Packages" value="C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\NuGetPackages\" />
    <add key="test1" value="https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/xx/xx/_packaging/xx/nuget/v3/index.json" />
  </packageSources>


  <packageSourceCredentials>
    <test1>
        <add key="Username" value="123" />
        <add key="Password" value="based64PAT" />
      </test1>
  </packageSourceCredentials>
</configuration>
```

Refer to the doc: [packageSourceCredentials](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/nuget-config-file#packagesourcecredentials)

Comment: This solved my problem. I had authorized the build service of my project as contributor, but not the project collection build service.